# Regex expand to sentence, stop at punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a pretty solid regex so far, that expands a selected text to the sentence(s). There is one special case I couldn't solve yet.

```
/[.:!?]([^.:!?]*?SELECTED TEXT\..*?[.:!?])/g
```

If I select text and a punctuation mark is at the very end of the selection, the current regex expression includes the next sentence as well. It would be great if that wouldn't happen.

Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/eS5jD9/4

Comment: Try using `[.:!?]([^.:!?]*?SELECTED TEXT\.*?[.:!?])`

Comment: Perhaps, you need to allow the same subpattern *after* the selected text? Like `[.:!?]([^.:!?]*?pulvinar felis[^.:!?]*(?:$|[.:!?]))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\.` is not required in your regex. Removing it should fix your problem

```
/[.:!?]([^.:!?]*?SELECTED TEXT.*?[.:!?])/g
```

Comment: I know it's not required but the user might hightlight it and it would become a part of the selected text. But I could just trim it of.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ending match any `.*?`

```
[.:!?]([^.:!?]*?pulvinar felis[.:!?])
```

[**Regex Domo**](https://regex101.com/r/eS5jD9/5)

Comment: No quite. I don't know what the user will highlight and how the selected text will look like.